# При использовании pytube видео может скачиваться бесконечно и заполнять все пространство на диске

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

Написал скрипт для скачивания видео с YT, используя pytube, через него очень часто проходят разные видео длительностью до 5 минут и 30 секунд (программное ограничение). При каждом запросе запускается отдельный поток под скачивание (используется threading). Помимо потоков со скачиванием нередко запускаются еще и потоки связанные со скачиванием и обработкой файлов в тг. Но иногда происходит то, что пока обьяснить никто из моего окружения не смог: иногда скачивание видео будто зацикливается, что приводит к бесконечному раздуванию видео. Последний раз, когда такое произошло видео весило +- 500гб. То есть диск сервера забивается под ноль.
Опытным путем выяснил, что от самого видео это никак не зависит и виновато возможно окружение. Подскажите, каким образом можно отследить или найти источник всех проблем? Про фикс я пока молчу, ибо это что то крайне неочевидное и пока стоит понять хотя бы изза чего это происходит.

Скачиваю с помощью функции: `YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download(str(name), max_retries=3)`

Comment: На каких видео это происходит, конкретных или случайных? Если попытаться скачать "бесконечное" видео второй раз - скачается нормально?

Comment: Это происходит в абсолютно случайное время с абсолютно случайным видео. Я для теста пробовал в 20 потоках скачивать видео, вызвавшее ошибку - все нормально

Comment: Чуть подробнее изучил статьи по работе с потоками и пришел к новому выводу: Во всем виноват GIL. Пока не уверен как он влияет на загрузчик, но знаю точно, надо менять подход к работе с потоками. Скорее всего придется перейти в ассинхрон